# Applying ring homomorphism to coefficients of polynomial is a ring homomorphism?

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, polynomial-rings

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be rings, $\phi:R_1\to R_2$ some ring homomorphism. Consider the map $\widehat\phi$ that sends any polynomial $f(x) = \sum_ia_ix^i\in R_1[x]$ to $\widehat\phi(f(x)) = \sum_i\phi(a_i)x^i\in R_2[x]$.

Is $\widehat\phi$ a ring homomorphism? Clearly it respects addition, but I am having trouble verifying that it respects multiplication.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval is there something wrong with how I asked the question? or is the question too easy/trivial for this site?

Comment: Hint: It's enough to check it preserves multiplication on monomials, i.e polynomials of the form $ax^i$. (think why it is sufficient)

Comment: @node196884 When you ask a question, according to the rules of the forum you should write what you understand about the problem and what you tried, at least in a few words. Otherwise the question might get closed. All of that appears in the links from the first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f(x):=\sum_i a_ix^i$ and $g(x):=\sum_j b_jx^j$, we have $f(x)g(x)=\sum_k\sum_{i+j=k}a_ib_jx^k$, thus

$$\begin{align}\widehat\phi[f(x)g(x)]&=\sum_k\sum_{i+j=k}\phi(a_ib_j)x^k\\&=\sum_k\sum_{i+j=k}\phi(a_i)\phi(b_j)x^k\\&=[\sum_i \phi(a_i)x^i][\sum_j\phi(b_j)x^j]=\ldots\end{align}$$